# How to use --globalOptions argument when starting Highcharts Node.js Export Server

Tags: json, highcharts, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to start my highchart export server with the [comand line argument](https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server#command-line-arguments) "--globalOptions" to hide the contextmenu button in the exported charts.

I tried to start the server with this command (I'm using Ubuntu 20.04):

```
highcharts-export-server --host localhost --port 8080  --allowCodeExecution true --globalOptions '{\"exporting\":{\"enabled\":\"false\"}}'
```

The charts are exported to image as expected but they still have the context button:
[image: Output chart example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the config as follows:

```
exporting: {
        buttons: {
          contextButton: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }
      }
```

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.buttons.contextButton.enabled

Comment: Thank you I managed to make it work with this config.